# Can I assign an address of file descriptor to a variable?

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I need to use shared memory to communication between processes, and I wandered if I can assign the address of shared memory file descriptor or an common file descriptor to a pointer which points to a struct or vector/map?

for example,`addr` if the address of a shared memory

```
Struct A{...};
A* stru = static_cast<A*>(addr);   // is this OK?
```

Comment: I think this depends on whether `A` is POD and how `addr` is aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should probably look at [Boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) and use it.

For a manual approach, read on.

For this to work, your struct must not use any pointers. It also must not have any virtual functions. If it's just a struct with non-pointer data members (meaning just built-in types, no `std::string` or `std::vector` or anything that isn't also a plain struct) and its member functions (if any) only operate on that data and do not call any non-member functions, then it should be safe to do.

You need to make sure the address is aligned correctly. You can explicitly check with:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
// ...

assert(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(addr) % alignof(A) == 0);
```

If the method you're using to create the shared memory allows you to specify the wanted alignment in bytes, then `alignof(A)` will give you the correct number of bytes.

The size of the memory must also be big enough (must be at least `sizeof(A)`.)

If it's of compatible alignment and size, you then must create your object in that memory using placement new:

```
#include <new>
// ...

auto stru = new(addr) A;
```

This will create the object `stru` in the memory pointed to by `addr`.

**Do not** call `delete` on that object. At the point where you would normally call `delete`, you should instead manually call the destructor:

```
stru->~A();
```

In order to make this easier, you should probably wrap this object in a `unique_ptr` with a custom lambda deleter that calls the destructor:

```
#include <memory>
// ...

auto a_dtor_caller = [](A* obj){ obj->~A(); };
auto stru = std::unique_ptr<A, decltype(a_dtor_caller)>(new(addr) A, a_dtor_caller);
```

`stru` is now a `unique_ptr` and the `A` instance it manages will be correctly destructed when it goes out of scope.

The above should only be done once. Other processes that just need access to the object should just use:

```
A* stru = static_cast<A*>(addr);
```

It goes without saying that they should also never `delete` the object nor call its destructor. Only the `unique_ptr` that manages the object should do that.

When you're about to free the shared memory, you need to first destroy the object. If your code doesn't naturally let the `unique_ptr` "expire" before you free the shared memory, then you must do so manually with:

```
stru.reset();
```

This will destruct the object and `stru` is now effectively a `nullptr`.

All in all, I really recommend Boost.interprocess instead. Less error-prone.

Comment: thanks, Can I just close the shared memory and make s=NULL when I want to 'delete' it?

Comment: @maidamai I updated the answer on how to destruct the object prior to freeing the shared memory.

Comment: @maidamai I forgot to mention that it's only possible to do this safely for plain structs. See newly added first paragraph in the answer.

Comment: @ Nikos C  Is there any easier ways to share  struct  between processes?

Comment: @maidamai There's the Boost.interprocess library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess.html). Make sure to read the "Limitations When Constructing Objects In Mapped Regions" section on that page. Using Boost is recommended, since the manual approach (as given in this answer) is not really the safest thing to do. Boost will be a bit more complicated to get used to, but I highly recommend using it. It will give you a safer way to use objects in shared memory.